# how to avoid a automatic logout using spring security

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-security

i'm fighting with a strange problem using the spring security core plugin. after a successful login clicking on any secured link causes a automatic logout of the current user. it's very hard to determine the reason because this behaviour happens only in some cases. the application is secured by using request maps. there is no exception and the request maps are correctly configured.

grails 1.3.7, spring security core plugin 1.2.1

Comment: Only in some cases? Can you post your spring-security configuration?  Maybe the links that fail require the user to have a different role, that could be the reason why spring-security forces the user to login again.

Comment: Also, could you please confirm that you are actually logged out and not just appear to be logged out because of security taglib stuff.

For example if you have <sec:ifNotLoggedIn> to show your login box at the top or something, I've noticed this taglib to show you as not logged in if you hit a custom 404 or 403.

I am still hunting the reason and I am planning to file a JIRA for it.

Comment: the user is definitely logged in and has assigned the right role for the urls. i found out that the some links pointing to the start page, which contains the login form, are not consistent. some including www and some not. the grails server url is configured without www. i have to check the url in several places like tomcat config, grails config, firewall and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was the misconfiguration of the server url. in some places www were used and in some configrations not. so make sure your are using the same server url for the app, e.g. in tomcat config, isa server config, app config, ...